# How to get a circle image in UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I tried to get a circle image using layer, here is my code

```
_compassArrow.layer.cornerRadius = _compassArrow.frame.size.width / 2;
_compassArrow.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
_compassArrow.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor
```

the compassArrow is an imageview which display the compass image. And when I run my program, it looks terrible:

[my actual picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxyez.png)

I don't know what happened to it. I've add some constraints to it, to make it has equal width with the device. Does this influence my image?

Comment: Where are you running this code?

Comment: if your height and width are different than this will happen. Check your height/width are equal or not. It is mandatory to have equal height/width of uiimageview if you are using layer property to make uiimageview circuler.

Comment: Look at my answer, pretty sure it's coming from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you set cornerRadius before your constraints are applied. Try to put this code in `layoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` for example.

This way, the `_compassArrow.frame.size.width` value will be the one after constraints applied on it, and you'll get the correct cornerRadius.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much. It seems that I have to learn more about the details of the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that should allow you to do this.

```
        _compassArrow.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        _compassArrow.layer.masksToBounds = false
        _compassArrow.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        _compassArrow.layer.cornerRadius = profilePicture.frame.size.width/2
        _compassArrow.clipsToBounds = true
```